# HTML pingback disable for iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have a player from some site in an iframe, they have changed the player url and now use

```
<link rel="pingback" href="http://www.sitename.com/xmlrpc.php" />
```

When I open my site now, which has the iframe, it redirects me to their site, completely changing my domain name to them,

Is it possible to disable this?

thanks

Comment: if they've got framebuster code in there, then there's not much you can do, short of asking how you can (legally) embed their site in yours.

Comment: this is the site , from where i have iframed,
http://www.ghanalive.tv/afcon-2015/

Comment: i would appropriate if you can guide me for this,

Comment: this is what they have used 
<script>
if (window.top !== window.self) window.top.location.replace(window.self.location.href);
</script>

Comment: There are framebuster busters, but then there are also framebuster buster busters. Best to just contact the site and ask for a solution, or to stop iframing it. Clearly they don't want you displaying their site in an iframe.

Comment: so yeah, they've got framebusters, which means you should take it as a hint that they DON'T want their content framed. Contact the site's operators and see if there's a PROPER way to do this. If they don't allow framing, then you should respect their wishes and stop trying to steal their content anyways.

Comment: yes i agree, but now what motivates me , that if there is a solution to disable frambusters, i would love to learn this trick that might can be helpful to create more security for online products.

Comment: Isn't the product theirs to secure?

Comment: ok i have bypassed the buster with this code, applied in my <body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {                       
         return "This will end your session";
    }
</script>

Comment: now its giving an option to change window, a popup, now the question is how to eleminate that, 

dont worry , i am a tester for this project so i have to keep breaking it , in order to secure it more,

so now , please guide me so i can disable the pop up massage that says to change my window or not